# Have watermarks in digital downloads ever been used to prosecute uploaders?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, european-union

Most digital downloads (music, ebooks) today are protected by watermarks. But I'm not aware of *any* high-profile cases where these watermarks have been used to prosecute uploaders of said works to e.g. download sites. Instead it's my impression that most court cases on illegal downloads centred on *users* of file sharing.

Have watermarks been used and are they used to prosecute *uploaders* in North America or the EU?